# Using node-pg-migrate programmatic api?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Anyone have some good examples on using node-pg-migrate programmatic api?
I was able to use the cli to run the migration scripts but using the api is giving me some issues.

I'm currently writing a lambda using the serverless framework.

**handler.js**

```
import pg_migrate from 'node-pg-migrate';

   const databaseUrl = postgres://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.DB_HOST}:${process.env.DB_PORT}/${process.env.DB_NAME}
   let up : 'up'

   const options = {
        "databaseUrl": databaseUrl,
        "migrationsTable": "pgmigrations",
        "dir": "migrations",
        "direction": up,
        "count": 1,
        "ignorePattern": ""
   }

   pg_migrate(options);
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error: Client has already been connected. You cannot reuse a client.
>
> Error: Can't get migration files: Error: Cannot find module "."
>       at webpackMissingModule ..........
>
> The database connection is correct and the database is up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4790644/jan-dole%C5%BEel . 
Hi Jan,  would you be able to provide some insight on this please?  Thanks